# AWS IAM action cloudformation:GetTemplateSummary only works with resource "*"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I was trying to create an IAM policy that allows CloudFormation actions to be taken for specific resources in the account.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:DetectStackDrift",
                "cloudformation:CancelUpdateStack",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackInstance",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackResources",
                "cloudformation:SignalResource",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackResource",
                "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DeleteChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "cloudformation:ContinueUpdateRollback",
                "cloudformation:DetectStackResourceDrift",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackResourceDrifts",
                "cloudformation:GetStackPolicy",
                "cloudformation:GetTemplateSummary",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents",
                "cloudformation:CreateStack",
                "cloudformation:GetTemplate",
                "cloudformation:DeleteStack",
                "cloudformation:TagResource",
                "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
                "cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:ListChangeSets",
                "cloudformation:ListStackResources"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:*:*:stack/*/*",
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:*:*:stackset/*:*",
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:*:*:stack",
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:*:*:stackset",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, when I go to create a stack from a template saved in S3 (specifying S3 URL), I get blocked with an AccessDenied error.

```
User is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:GetTemplateSummary
```

If I add the following block, I do not run into the error.

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "cloudformation:GetTemplateSummary",
  "Resource": [
    "*"
  ]
}
```

I'm working in a corporate environment where we're not allowed to have wildcards like that for resources. What is the proper way to specify resources for this action?

---

I found AWS's documentation for CloudFormation actions and resources (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_awscloudformation.html). It says the GetTemplateSummary action has `stack` and `stackset` resource types, but those resources were allowed in my original policy. What resource types does GetTemplateSummary act on?

Comment: Quick sanity check: are the partitions in the ARNs correct for the partition you're working in? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arns-syntax

Comment: @PatMyron Thanks for the documentation, I had not seen that before. Yes, the partition should be correct. All my resources are in `us-east-1` which is in the `aws` partition.